# I couldn't get the value from the user controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, master-pages, multilingual

here is the my question.I have a master page which contain some flags to set the web page language.

inside the master page I have a user controller which contains menu items. These menu items depend on the flag chose, it change.

when I look at the life cycle of the web application ,first run, mainpage_loader,later run the user control loader,in the end,
run the function (flag button function ) defined inside the main page.

but what I need that is get the session value,inside the user control. Depends on the this session value,load the menu depends on language chosen.
but in this case I never catch the session value,inside user control as after pass the step masterpage function.
how can I solve this problem. thanks.

MY MASTER PAGE

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (Session["lang"]==null)
                {
                    Session["lang"] = "m_en";

                }
                else
                {

                }

            }


         [DirectMethod(IDMode = DirectMethodProxyIDMode.None)]
            public void Change_Lang_Event(string lang)
            {    
                CultureInfo ci;

                switch (lang)
                {
                    case "m_tr":
                        ci = new CultureInfo("tr-TR");
                        Session["lang"] = "m_tr";
//problem is here I coulnt reach Language properti
       ((UserControl)Page.Master.FindControl("MyMenu1")).Language = Session["lang"].ToString();


                        break;
                    case "m_en":
                        ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
                        Session["lang"] = "m_en";



                        break;
                    case "m_ru":
                        ci = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");
                        Session["lang"] = "m_ru";




                    default:
                       ci = new CultureInfo("tr-TR");
                        Session["lang"] = "m_tr";


                        break;
                }
```

MY USERCONTROL :

```
 public partial class MyMenu : System.Web.UI.UserControl

{
    static List<Ofis> lst;
    static CultureInfo cim;
    string dilSesion = "";
    private string _languages;

    public string Languages
    {
        get { return _languages; }
        set { _languages = value; }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       dilSesion =   Session["lang"].ToString();
      X.Msg.Alert("Uyarı", dilSesion).Show();


    }



}
```

Main aspx;

```
 <asp:Contentplaceholder id="Contentplaceholder1" runat="server">
            <uc1:MyMenu ID="MyMenu1" runat="server" />
        </asp:Contentplaceholder>
```

Comment: Nice one, please accept if it worked for you. :) Thanks.

Comment: Still tring if it works ,wait 5 minutes,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define a property in the UserControl i.e.

```
private string _language;

public string Language
{
    get
    {
        return _language;
    }

    get
    {
        return _language;
    }

}
```

Then you could set it in the MasterPage code behind:

```
((UserControl)Page.Master.FindControl('controlID')).Language = Session["lang"].ToString()
```

Please note the user control will have to be cast to your UserControl class.

Comment: I coulnt reach the language properties

Comment: I've updated it to add a cast, it will need to be cast to your user control class to make the property visible.

Comment: dear still it is unvissiable

Comment: it says me system.web.ui.usercontroler dosent caontain a definition Language

Comment: Update your answer with the full UserControl code and I'll be able to see what's going on please.

Comment: dear friend I am getting null reference exception when tryng to run                  ((MyMenu)Page.Master.FindControl("MyMenu1")).Languages = Session["lang"].ToString();hoe can I solve this

Comment: I would break it down by seeing if you get the control back first and null check. Does this return the control var myMenu1 = ((MyMenu)Page.Master.FindControl("MyMenu1"))

Comment: You might have to add viewstate around the properties too, there's lots of info on web about it.